# IF..ELSE-statement in SQL SELECT?

Tags: sql, subquery, feed, if-statement

I'm trying to make a user activity feed that only displays users' activities who are friends of the logged-in user.

The fields user1 and user2 are the friend request sender and friend request receiver. The problem is that the logged-in user could be in either field so I'm wondering how I can make an `if..else` statement for this particular issue.

Basically I want:

```
IF user2 is $log_username SELECT user1 FROM friends...
ELSE
SELECT user2 FROM friends.
```

The boldfaced code(subquery) is the one I'm referring to specifically.

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM status 
WHERE author in (
        SELECT user2 FROM friends 
        WHERE user1='$log_username'
          AND accepted='1' 
           OR user2='$log_username' 
          AND accepted='1'
    ) AND type='a' 
";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `IF` within an SQL Statement is `CASE`. Something like this (not sure if this gives you what you want but just to demonstrate the concept).

```
$sql = "
SELECT * FROM status 
WHERE author in (
        SELECT CASE WHEN user2 = '$log_username' THEN user1 ELSE user2
               END
         FROM friends 
        WHERE user1='$log_username'
          AND accepted='1' 
           OR user2='$log_username' 
          AND accepted='1'
    ) AND type='a' 
";
```

Comment: It gives me these errors: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:...\home.php on line 37

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:...\home.php on line 38.                        Those two lines are the last two: $query = mysqli_query($larue, $sql);
$statusnumrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { Thanks!

Comment: Changed something: `$log_username` has to be in single quotes just as in the `WHERE` clause. But again, i wanted you to give just the general concept so that you can work it out for yourself.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you so much! I can't really express how grateful I am for your help. Just, thank you much!(:

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM status WHERE author IN  
    (SELECT user1 FROM friends WHERE user1='$log_username' AND accepted='1'
     UNION 
    SELECT user2 FROM friends WHERE user2='$log_username' AND accepted='1')";
```

Comment: would the CASE clause work for this? I'm doing some research and it keeps popping up. And if so, do you know how? Because UNION is giving me errors.